# Filter output to get everything before the first dash and number

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I need to filter everything  every possible string before the dash and the number

```
fcp-workflow-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

Example:

```
fcp-workflow-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

Must always get: `fcp-workflow` or whatever the name is.

The name could be `fcp-worklflow-something-another-4.1.3....` meaning I don't know the length.

I've tried using `cut -d`, but since the length can change maybe a method with `grep` would do the work.

Here are more examples:

```
fcp-test-content-REVIEW-1.0-1.0.zip
dhl-pages-i18n-tags-blueprints-1.0.zip
GlobalLink Connect Plus-6.1.1_SP1.zip
logistics-ui-4.5.0-SNAPSHOT.zip"
logistics-ui-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT.zip"
```

Comment: Is it ensured that the part before that contains no numbers? Is the relevant number always in the `X.Y.Z` format?

Comment: What do you mean "before the line" ? Where are you doing this? Will you parse a file or is it a string? What is the exact command you have tried? Why don't you add 2-3 representative lines with what you mean?

Comment: @thanasisp I think "before the line" is "before the dash"...

Comment: Are these filenames, or text in a file?

Comment: The examples are already helpful, but we would need to see the associated desired output, too.

Comment: They could be in a variable or in a file. Both options are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get everything before the first dash followed by a digit:

```
sed -E 's/-[[:digit:]].*$//' file
```

by replacing from first dash and digit to the end of line with the empty string.

---

For your example, I see `-i18n` into a line that was lucky enough to survive. Probably you would like to have a more strict requirement, for example matching the first dash + number + dot + number would be like this:

```
sed -E 's/-[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+.*$//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash parameter expansion to remove the longest string following a dash and a digit:

```
for file in *
do
  printf '%s turns into %s\n' "${file}" "${file%%-[[:digit:]]*}"
done
```

Comment: I think that works. More tests I will make and come back to you